# using extended Toolkit Richtext box with mvvm to bind color text

Tags: wpf, mvvm, richtextbox

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class Line
{
   public Color Color { get; set; }
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using mvvm and right now i'm have have a string properity that i bind Text to, my xaml looks like this

```
<toolkit:RichTextBox Text="{Binding Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Ideal" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

I originally had this set up with a list box and was able to Convert my color without to much trouble, however I'm failing to see how to do this with rtb.  Only thing i can think of of the top is to add rtf formatting to the string prior to updating my property.  I'm guessing there is a simpler solution though?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the toolkit RTB supports this but if you did not try it yet you could see if setting `TextElement.Foreground` works:

```
<RichTextBox ...>
    <TextElement.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}" />
    </TextElement.Foreground>
```

Comment: this works if you just have one string.  I'm looking to bind either a collection of type Line.. or I guess append a line to the text property. Each line should maintain its own color.

Comment: @poco: Can't you then just set that property on each Line instead?

Comment: with a list box i can with no problems.  Problem that I'm having with a list box is I can't highlight and copy selected text. I can copy the entire listbox item, but not the behavior I'm looking for.  I'm thinking that an rtb is the control I'm needing to use, just can't seem to understand the proper implementation.

Comment: @poco: I can't help you in that case as i have never used the RTB of the WPF Toolkit, sorry.